# Python - неправильный return

Tags: python

Пытаюсь написать функционал, задачи которой из переменной получить значение, сравнить его и выдать правильную модель Raspberry Pi

```
@app.route('/raspname', methods=['GET'])
def raspiname():
global model_name
if myrevision == 'a01041' or 'a21041':
    model_name = 'Pi 2 Model B'
if myrevision == 'a02082' or 'a22082':
    model_name = 'Pi 3 Model B'
if myrevision == '0002':
    model_name = 'Model B Revision 1.0'
if myrevision == '0003':
    model_name = 'Model B Revision 1.0 + ECN0001'
if myrevision == '0004' or '0005' or '0006':
    model_name = 'Model B Revision 2.0'
if myrevision == '0007' or '0008' or '0009':
    model_name == 'Model A'
if myrevision == '000d' or '000e' or '000f':
    model_name = 'Model B Revision 2.0'
if myrevision == '0010':
    model_name = 'Model B+'
if myrevision == '0011':
    model_name = 'Compute Module'
if myrevision == '0012':
    model_name = 'Model A+'
else:
    model_name = 'Raspberry Pi'
return 'Model name - %s' % model_name
```

всегда выдает `Raspberry Pi`. Не могу понять, почему так не работает

Comment: Подозреваю, что должно быть `global myrevision`, а не `global model_name`.

Comment: Замените `if` кроме первого на `elif`. На данный момент у вас работает только последнее условие.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Неправильно пользуетесь условиями.

```
if myrevision == '0012':
    model_name = 'Model A+'
else:
    model_name = 'Raspberry Pi'
```

Это условие является решающим, поэтому возможны только два значения из этого условия.

Используйте правильный синтаксис:

```
if ...
    ...
elif ...
    ...
elif ...
    ...
else ...
    ...
```